# UPDATE statement conflict with FOREIGN KEY constraint in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, sql-server-2008-r2, domain-driven-design

I am actually working on an ASP.NET MVC4 application where we used the entity framework and the Model-View-View-Model approach and 7-layered architecture. We have one page where we need to insert or update "Product" information. The inserted or updated Product data will be saved inside "Product" table. My database name is "DbOnix".
The basic structure of Product Table is given below:

```
 Column Name               Data Type      Allow Nulls
ProductID PK                  int           
ProductName                varchar(255)       NO
ProductCategoryID FK          int             
Sequence                      int             YES
ActiveStatus                  int             YES
SlNo                          int             NO
```

The ProductCategoryID column in Product table has a foreign key relationship with the ProductCategory table. The basic structure of ProductCategory table:

```
    Column Name                Data Type          Allow Nulls
 ProductCategoryID PK             int                          
 ProductCategoryName            varchar(150)          NO
```

Whenever I'm trying to insert or update data in the Product table, the following exception is thrown:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint   "FK_Product_ProductCategory". The conflict occurred in database "DbOnix", table "dbo.ProductCategory", column 'ProductCategoryID'.The statement has been terminated.
```

My Controller Code:

```
    public HttpStatusCodeResult UpdateProductInformation(int id, ProductDTO ProductDTO)
    {
        _productManager.UpdateProductInformation(id, ProductDTO);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

My Manager Class Code:

```
    public void UpdateProductInformation(int id, ProductDTO productDTO)
    {
        //if productDTO data is not valid
        if (productDTO == null)
            throw new  ArgumentException(Messages.warning_CannotAddProfileWithNullInformation);

        //Create a new product entity
        var currentProduct = _ProductRepository.Get(id);

        var updatedProduct = new Product();
        updatedProduct.ProductID = id;
        updatedProduct.ProductName = productDTO.ProductName;
        updatedProduct.ProductCategoryID = productDTO.ProductCategoryID;
        updatedProduct.Sequence = productDTO.Sequence;
        updatedProduct.ActiveStatus = productDTO.ActiveStatus;
        updatedProduct.SlNo = productDTO.SlNo;

        //Update Product
        updatedProduct = this.UpdateProduct(currentProduct, updatedProduct);

    }
```

My Core (Property) Class code:

```
public partial class Product : Entity, IValidatableObject
{


    public Product()
    {

    }


    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public int ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    public int SlNo { get; set; }
}
```

and my DTO Class code:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public int ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    public int SlNo { get; set; }
}
```

Note that my Database Server is MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

EDIT-1: I forgot to include my Javascript code:

```
$(function () {



var Product = function (Product) {
    var self = this;
    self.ProductID = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ProductID : 0).extend({ required: true });
    self.ProductName = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ProductName : '').extend({ required: true });
    self.ActiveStatus = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ActiveStatus : 0);

};

var ProductCollection = function () {
    var self = this;

    //if ProfileId is 0, It means Create new Profile
    if (ProductID == 0) {
        self.Product = ko.observable(new Product());
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlProduct + '/GetProductById/' + ProductID,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                self.Product = ko.observable(new Product(json));
            }
        });
    }

    self.ProductErrors = ko.validation.group(self.Product());





    self.saveProduct = function () {
        var isValid = true;

        if (self.ProductErrors().length != 0) {
            self.ProductErrors.showAllMessages();
            isValid = false;
        }



        if (isValid) {

            self.Product().ActiveStatus = document.getElementById("stat").value;

            $.ajax({
                type: (ProductID > 0 ? 'PUT' : 'POST'),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: urlProduct + (ProductID > 0 ? '/UpdateProductInformation?id=' + ProductID : '/SaveProductInformation'),
                data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.Product())),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Product saved successfully.");
                    window.location.href = '/Product';
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    var err = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
                    var errors = "";
                    for (var key in err) {
                        if (err.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            errors += key.replace("Product.", "") + " : " + err[key];
                        }
                    }
                    $("<div></div>").html(errors).dialog({ modal: true, title: JSON.parse(err.responseText).Message, buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } } }).show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
        }
    };
};


var ProductsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var url = "/Product/GetAllProduct";
    var refresh = function () {
        $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
            self.Products(data);
        });
    };

    // Public data properties
    self.Products = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Public operations
    self.createProduct = function () {
        window.location.href = '/Product/ProductCreateEdit/0';
    };

    self.editProduct = function (product) {
        //alert(product.ProductID);
        window.location.href = '/Product/ProductCreateEdit/' + product.ProductID;
    };

};

    ko.applyBindings(new ProductsViewModel(), document.getElementById("productlist"));
    ko.applyBindings(new ProductCollection(), document.getElementById("product_edit"));
});
```

Note that I used KnockoutJS v2.3.0

Comment: Are you sure that `productDTO.ProductCategoryID` in `UpdateProductInformation(int id, ProductDTO productDTO)` has right value? It seems that you try to enter not existed `ProductCategoryID`.

Comment: As Roman Izosimov said, you may be trying to add a `Product` with a `ProductCategoryID` that doesn't already exist in the `ProductCategory` table.

Comment: About adding a new Product, yes, it seems that a null value is being saved in the ProductCategoryID column because I haven't actually declared any properties in the Javascript file. But while I try to update an existing product, there is definitely some valid value in the ProductCategoryID table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code ..

```
updatedProduct.ProductCategoryID = productDTO.ProductCategoryID;
```

there may be you are assigning a value  (ProductCategoryID) which is not exists in the  **ProductCategory** table. So please check whether you get the correct  ProductCategories(check **productDTO**)  from the database. The issue may be the value of your  ProductCategoryID is **0**.
Thats why it says `UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`

Comment: Yes, I am getting the value 0 in ProductCategoryID while trying to update. I discovered it while debugging. But what's the exact reason of this???? While I'm trying to retrieve the data, ProductCategoryID is not 0, rather it returns a  valid value. Getting more and more confused.

Comment: may be in the middle you are doing something to your retrieved data. (Assigning to a new object or something else). Debug and check you data loading part to see where your  ProductCategoryID  value getting 0..

Comment: ProductCategoryID value gets 0 when I click on the Update button. Upon clicking Update button, the saveProduct method in the Javascript is called, then in Ajax, the UpdateProductInformation method is called, which is in the controller.

Comment: It seems to be your object is refreshing when you click Update button. Check whether all the fields in your DTO getting zero or default when you click Update button. Are you using Viewstates or Sessions in this

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in the Javascript code:

```
$(function () {



    var Product = function (Product) {
    var self = this;
    self.ProductID = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ProductID : 0).extend({ required: true });
    self.ProductName = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ProductName : '').extend({ required: true });
    self.ActiveStatus = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ActiveStatus : 0);

};
```

There was no such thing as ProductCategoryID inside my Javascript code. Without this property, ProductCategoryID value couldn't be bound.

All I had to do was to add this bit to the above code snippet:

```
self.ProductCategoryID = ko.observable(Product ? Product.ProductCategoryID : 0).extend({required : true});
```

And then it worked perfectly.